# FPGA configuration time and PCI Express

Tags: fpga, pcie

I'm designing a PCI Express board with an Artix-7 from Xilinx. I'm reading through [the PCIe block description](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/pcie_7x/v3_3/pg054-7series-pcie.pdf) and on page 199 it says:

> Section 6.6 of PCI Express Base Specification, rev 1.1 states “A
>   system must guarantee that all components intended to be software
>   visible at boot time are ready to receive Configuration Requests
>   within 100 ms of the end of Fundamental Reset at the Root Complex.”

This is fine. It seems I can easily sequence the power supplies and config the FPGA in 100ms, but I'd like to understand how much time I have anyway.

The document then shows this:[image: Power Up]

and says:

> Section 2.6.2 of the PCI Express Card Electromechanical Specification,
>   v1.1 [Ref 2] defines TPVPREL as a minimum of 100 ms, indicating that
>   from the time power is stable the system reset is asserted for at
>   least 100 ms

Lastly, on page 201 it says:

> Figure 3-92 shows that power is valid before PWR_OK is asserted High.
>   This is represented by T3 and is the PWR_OK delay. The ATX 12V Power
>   Supply Design Guide defines PWR_OK as 100 ms < T3 < 500 ms, indicating
>   that from the point at which the power level reaches 95% of nominal,
>   there is a minimum of at least 100 ms but no more than 500 ms of delay
>   before PWR_OK is asserted. Remember, according to the PCI Express Card
>   Electromechanical Specification [Ref 2], the PERST# is guaranteed to
>   be asserted a minimum of 100 ms from when power is stable indicated in
>   an ATX system by the assertion of PWR_OK.

So it seems I should have at lest 300ms from when the power is within 95% of nominal:

- 100ms until PWR_OK - TPWRVLD
- 100ms from PWR_OK to end of PERST# - TPVPERL
- and then finally I have to be ready to respond 100ms after end of PERST#.

However, Equation 3-1 in the document says:

> FPGA Configuration Time ≤ TPWRVLD + TPVPERL

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your question?  The equation gives you a constraint on the FPGA configuration time.  If you can meet that, you should be OK.  If you can't, it won't work :(

Comment: My question is why the time they give is 200ms when there are at least 3 periods of 100ms before it needs to receive configuration requests.

Comment: Ahh, I see... so you mean that the equation should be `FPGA Configuration Time ≤ TPWRVLD + TPVPERL + 100ms`

Comment: Yes, but I think I figured it out. From when the reset ends I have 100ms to start receiving configurations requests, but only 20ms for link training, so I actually have 220ms to be at least partially configured.

Comment: Can you do *anything* before PWR_OK? or do you actually lose that time because you don't have a guaranteed power supply?

Comment: With an ATX board the supplies have to be within 95% of the final value for 100ms before PWR_OK goes up. I can use that time with the supplies I have, so I should be fine. I can configure my XC7A50T with time to spare. I also have an external supply in case of problems. I'm not that worried about it working, just wanted to understand the constraints better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90043/discussion-between-martin-thompson-and-lnowak).